# Django order by foreign key

Tags: python, django, sorting, model, foreign-keys

I was programming a function in python that required a group of objects of a model to be ordered by a specific parameter (the codename of a problem), this parameter resulted to be a string. When I sorted it inside the Problems table, it worked correctly, however, when I sorted it inside ProblemUser model (using order_by) the sort was completely incorrect respecting the real results.

I managed to work it around by sorting the elements AFTER i got it from the model using sorted() function, however, i am still with the doubt on how to sort a foreign key in the order_by function.

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    problem_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='Unnamed')
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='UNRATED')

class ProblemUser(models.Model):
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)
    handler = models.ForeignKey(Handler)
    solved = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    entry = models.DateField()


t = ProblemUser.objects.filter(solved=1, handler=Handler.objects.get(id=1)).order_by('problem')

t[0].problem.codename < t[42].problem.codename
False

t[1].problem.codename < t[42].problem.codename
True
```

I also tried order_by('problem__codename')

Some codenames examples are (these are outputs that i remember to have seen when i ordered by the foreign key):

> S_1_T 
>   S_1000_E
>   S_1001_F
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   S_2_P

Thank you for your time and help! :).

Comment: Order by problem.problem_name?

Comment: How do you expect it to be sorted? Also, how do you define the order when querying for just the `Problem` model? On a side note, `handler=Handler.objects.get(id=1)` can be simplified to `handler_id=1`, this saves you a subquery.

Comment: I don't want to order by problem name, problem name it is not the same as codename. On the other hand, I added a meta to set the ordering to codename, didn't worked neither. The order should be ascending.

Answer (score 1):

try it like that please.

```
t = ProblemUser.objects.filter(solved=1, handler=Handler.objects.get(id=1)).order_by('problem__codename')
```

Comment: Problem name and problem codename are not the same, in addition, problem codename is the primary key

Comment: sorry I didn't notice. I changed it now.